# NestJS - JWT not working anymore after reseed

Tags: authentication, jwt, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to use the same jwt to authenticate against a Nest backend across server reseeds. When I say 'reseed', I mean

```
npm run schema:drop && npm run migration:run
```

In the migration, a user is created with a predefined username and password - Logging in with username and password indeed works across reseeds, but a previously acquired jwt doesn't work anymore after reseeding.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Do you have changing columns ? `createdAt`, `updatedAt` or `deletedAt` for example

Comment: Yes, all entities inherit from an entity with these properties

Comment: Could have many reasons. For one, check if your jwt has expired.

Comment: The JWT content will be different every time if you include the traceability entity and with a different expiration date